# How to set borders of linkers in chord diagram darker compared to inner transparent fill in R

Tags: r, chord-diagram

I want to create the border for the linkers of the chord diagram darker compared to the inner fill
An example of data similar to the one I am working on is

```
set.seed(999)
mat = matrix(sample(18, 18), 3, 6) 
rownames(mat) = paste0("S", 1:3)
colnames(mat) = paste0("E", 1:6)
mat
df = data.frame(from = rep(rownames(mat), times = ncol(mat)),
    to = rep(colnames(mat), each = nrow(mat)),
    value = as.vector(mat),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

the code i am using is

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
chordDiagram(mat, order = c("S2", "S1", "S3", "E4", "E1", "E5", "E2", "E6", "E3"))
```

Comment: Can you include the code you are using to make your chord diagram please? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're trying to change. [See if anything in this resource helps.](https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/the-chorddiagram-function.html)

Comment: Hi kat thank you responding i want to make the outer boundary dark for the chords/links

Comment: chordDiagram(mat, grid.col = grid.col, link.lwd = lwd_mat, link.border = border_mat) as given in this command but this gives the border red color whereas i want the color that is customized for each link

Comment: i.e. if my link is blue in color with transparency of 0.5 i want the border for the chord/link of original blue color